# How to Dynamically add anchor tags to URL and scroll to heading if in URL

Tags: jquery, scroll, url-rewriting, anchor

I'm trying to build a feature using jQuery that will dynamically create hash anchor links based on header sections. Now if there's a URL with this hash, then I'd like to scroll to that section on page load. The problem is on page load, the browser will scroll to the correct anchor, the jump back to the top. So it works, but it doesn't stay.

I understand that the issue here is the anchor tag doesn't exist when the page loads, so I have to wait for the elements to be added before performing any scrolling.

What I've tried to do is:

- cache the hash and URL
- get the hash
- remove it from the URL (`replaceState`)
- used the cached hash to scroll to the section
- Return the URL to it's original stage using `replaceState` again

```
var HeaderAnchors = function(el){

    //setup some variables
    this.$el        = $(el);
    this.$headers   = this.$el.find( 'h2, h3' );
    this.headerSlugs= [];
    this.urlHash    = window.location.hash;
    this.url        = window.location.href;

    this.init();

};

HeaderAnchors.prototype.init = function(){

    new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

        this.createAnchors();

        return resolve();

    } )
    .then( ()=>{

        //check if there is hash and if the hash is in the array of headings
        if( this.urlHash && this.headerSlugs.includes( this.urlHash.substring(1) ) ){

            //disable the anchor from jumping
            history.replaceState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);

            //smooth scroll to the stop of the hash, which has the same ID as the hash
            Foundation.SmoothScroll.scrollToLoc( this.urlHash, {
                threshold: 50,
                offset: 100,
                animationDuration: 200
            }, ()=>{

                //add the url back to
                window.history.replaceState({ path: this.url }, '', this.url);

            });

        }

    } );


};

HeaderAnchors.prototype.createAnchors = function(){

    this.$headers.each( ( index, val )=>{

        const heading       = $(val);
        const headingText   = heading
            .text()
            .toLowerCase()
            .trim()
            .replace( /[^\w\s]/gi, '' )
            .replace(/ +/g,'-');

        this.headerSlugs.push( headingText );

        let hashIcon = $('<span />')
            .addClass( 'fas fa-hashtag' )
            .attr({
                'aria-hidden' : 'true'
            });

        let anchor = $('<a />')
            .attr({
                'href'  : `#${headingText}`,
                'class' : 'c-anchor-hash__link'

            })
            .append( hashIcon );

        heading
            .addClass( 'c-anchor-hash' )
            .attr( { 'id'    : headingText} )
            .prepend( anchor );

    } );
};
```

I'm expecting the anchor to scroll to the dynamically created anchor... and it does... but then it jumps back up...

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: have you already tried using a `setTimeout` to run the scroll function after everything is loaded?

Comment: @mjw yea I have tried set `setTimeout` for like 200ms... and it works by scrolling down, then it jumps back up to top of page

Answer (score 0):

the solution to your problem is simple. you are taking it too far.
Just do this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#gen").click(function() {
    $("#HTMLdy").html('<a href="https://ess.com.ng">Click Me</a>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="HTMLdy"></div>
<button id="gen">Generate Anchor Tag</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @DUG but unfortunately, I'm getting the same result. The browser will jump the anchor tag, and then immediately jump back to the top of the page.

Comment: put the anchor tag in a div and ID that div